# rotate sphere horizontally around another sphere

Tags: opengl, rotation, jogl

I currently have an earth and a moon. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the moon physically rotate **around the earth horizontally along the equator** along a circular path.

```
    moonAngle = (moonAngle + 0.5f) % 360f;
    xPath = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(moonAngle)) * distance;
    yPath = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(moonAngle)) * distance;

    gl.glTranslatef(xPath, yPath, -30f);
```

The above works fine, except the moon is rotating around the earth **vertically around the Prime Meridian** like a wall clock. How do I adjust the angle of rotation? I've tried modifying the `glTranslatef`, but with no success.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, with horizontal and vertical rotation? The first thing that comes to my mind with "horizontal rotation" is the rotationing at the start of this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoQYw49saqc

Comment: Aren’t you just confusing Y and Z in the `glTranslatef` call?

Comment: @SamHocevar The problem is that I'm trying to maintain the z-position of -30f at the same time why moving along the X and Z paths which is also the same position as the zPosition as the earth. This way if I move the Earth along the zAxis, the moon will update accordingly as well.

Comment: @ChocoMan Then you might want to try `gl.glTranslatef(xPath, 0f, yPath-30f);`. But most of all you want to remove hardcoded values and use named variables for the Earth position.

Comment: @SamHocevar That was it. Works perfectly now. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: Okay, I made it into an answer, but I think the question is a bit too localised for the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Y` offset you are computing should actually be applied to the `Z` axis:

```
gl.glTranslatef(xPath, 0f, yPath - 30f);
```